# mule foreach payload

Tags: mule

I want to iterate some Arraylist value, so in Mule 3.3 having `foreach` for collection, I am using `foreach` to iterate the ArrayList.

Iteration is working fine, but after the iteration, I need the current payload. Instead of getting the current payload, I am getting the previous payload like `foreach` ArrayList.

```
    <flow name="">
    <component java="ArrayList"/>
    <foreach >
    <component java="getting arrayList value"/>
    </foreach>
    <logger message="DAVID#[payload]" />
```

Here I am getting java="ArrayList" instead of this payload "getting arrayList value"

Please help me to get the current payload over foreach .

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand your issue.

The doc states:

> The `MuleEvent` sent to the next message processor is the same that
>   arrived to foreach.

Isn't that what you're noticing? What else do you want?